# How to get same name or id from another table with matching name or id in another table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am using c# and mysql database
 I have 2 tables
1st is for info

```
(Int primary key)          (varchar)             (int)
    Id                       name                 year
   2015                      user1                 1
   2016                      user2                 2
```

2nd is for accounts

```
(Int primary key)        (varchar)               (varchar)
Id (username)              name                   password
2015                       user1                    123
2016                       user2                    123
```

I want to make query that if I would go to make an account with the same id(username) or name after the login then it will show it in datagrid, but I don't know what query I should use.

That means I want to get a result like this for every account which has the same id or name and not show all the data after the login

3rd table showed in datagrid

```
Id                                  name                 year
2015                                user1                  1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Id should be unique for each row, so you shouldn't have 2 users with same Id. Can you make it more clear ?

Comment: The 1st table is for student info actually its student ID not id only and the second table is for user account the first thing to do is im going to make an student info like student id, name, and year after i input that im going to make an account for that student the student id is the username and password is generated after i create an account for that student they will login their account then it will show their info such as student id, name, and year etc. Did you get it? Sorry im not good at english

Comment: select id, name, year from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.student_id (if you want to join tables)

Comment: acctually i try that `SELECT tblstudent.StudentID, tblstudent.Name, tblstudent.YearLevel FROM tblstudent INNER JOIN userstudent ON tblstudent.StudentID = userstudent.StudentID` thats the code i use but every time i login it shows all the data from tblstudent how can i show only 1?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 tblstudent.StudentID, tblstudent.Name, tblstudent.YearLevel FROM tblstudent INNER JOIN userstudent ON tblstudent.Name = userstudent.Name (if its sql server)

Comment: im using mysql xampp i try the SELECT TOP 1 but its not working

Comment: SELECT tblstudent.StudentID, tblstudent.Name, tblstudent.YearLevel FROM tblstudent INNER JOIN userstudent ON tblstudent.StudentID = userstudent.StudentID LIMIT 1 (mysql)

Comment: it works but the problem is only the 1st info i input will show after i login the other account its not showing only the 1st info only its shows

Answer (score 2):

When a user  does « login » then its id is available to the application. Just pass this id to a simple SELECT query (seems like you don’t even need a JOIN) :

```
SELECT
    tblstudent.StudentID, 
    tblstudent.Name, 
    tblstudent.YearLevel 
FROM
    tblstudent 
WHERE tblstudent.StudentID = ?
```

You want to replace the « ? » with the id of the student that just logged in.

Comment: it works but hows the other user account for their info? only the id i input their will show.

Comment: @GMB, it appears that it's not what Newb needs, just I wonder what is he needs :)

Comment: @Newb : well, then it is quite unclear what you really want... for example, how many rows do you expect in your output ?

Comment: @mirkoacimovic : well, from the comments I thought I understood what was requested... but not anymore !

Comment: only 1 row will show, example i input 3 student info(student1, student2, student3)  then i create an account for student1 after i create an account i will login their account then only student1 info will show, student 2 and 3 will not show, after that i will create an account for student2 then only student2 info will show and also for 3. did you get it? sorry im not good at english hehe

Comment: Ok so the query should do the job. After login, you have the student id ; pass it to the query (replace the « ? » with the id), and the corresponding data will be returned. For you what is the problem ?

Comment: every time i add student info i will add the id to query?

Comment: @newb : your application should pass the is to the query. When a user  does « login » then its id is available to the application, right ? Just pass it to the query. I’m updating my answer (it seems you don’t even need a join)

Comment: @Newb [Working with Parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html).

Comment: what will i put in the << ? >> i dont know

Comment: @Newb : I already responded to that : you replace the ? with the ID of the user that just logged in...

Comment: But only the ID i put their will show, how about the other ID for other student info